# Cambiar color y propiedades de texto en un AlertDialog

Tags: android, alertdialog

Tengo un `AlertDialog` que muestra un cierto mensaje que incluye dos variables, que son **correo** y **pass** y deseo poder asignarle un color. ¿ alguna idea de como realizar esto ?

Les dejo mi **AlertDialog**

```
        String correo=txtcorreo.getText().toString();
        String pass=txtpass.getText().toString();

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddCuentaExpositor.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("¿Esta seguro que desea crear la siguiente cuenta "+ correo + " con contraseña "+pass);

        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Si",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        final String email=txtcorreo.getText().toString();
                        final String password=txtpass.getText().toString();

                        new Asyncinsert().execute(email,password);
                    }
                });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();



    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existen varias formas, pero creo que la más sencilla sería esta, utilizando el color RGB y aplicando una transformación del código html, por ejemplo para cambiar el color del texto del mensaje a color rojo (`#FF0000`) se realizaría de esta forma:

```
 alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'>¿Esta seguro que desea crear la siguiente cuenta "+ correo + " con contraseña "+pass + "</font>"));
```

Esto mismo se puede aplicar al titulo.

Para cambiar el color únicamente a las variables `email` y `pass`, se realizaría de esta forma:

```
 alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("¿Esta seguro que desea crear la siguiente cuenta <font color='#FF0000'>"+ correo + "</font> con contraseña <font color='#FF0000'>"+pass + "</font>"));
```

---

**En realidad puedes usar varios tipos de tags html, por ejemplo si deseas texto "Bold", simplemente usa los contenedores `<b>` y `</b>`, texto "italic" `<i>` y `</i>`, texto de mayor tamaño mediante `<big>` y `</big>`** etc...:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego un ejemplo en código para documentar lo comentado en la respuesta:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        MainActivity.this);

// Configura el titulo.
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'>Author <b>Mihai Eminescu</b></font>"));

// Configura el mensaje.
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage(Html.fromHtml("Por la noche, perezoso y cárdeno, arde el <font color='#FF0000'>fuego</font> en la chimenea;\n" +
                    "desde <u>un rincón en un sofá</u>  <font color='#FF0000'>rojo</font> yo lo miro de frente,\n" +
                    "<b>hasta que mi mente se duerme, hasta que mis pestañas se bajan</b>;\n" +
                    "la vela está apagada en la casa... <i>el sueño es</i> <font color='#0000FF'>cálido</font>, lento, suave.<br><hr>"))
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, close
                // current activity
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
                // the dialog box and do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).create().show();
```

Comment: De esta forma cambia todo el texto a color rojo ? no existe la forma de solo cambiar el color de las variables email y pass ? o que queden como en formato BOLD

Comment: Ok he agregado eso en mi respuesta. @FelixBeeb

Comment: Como siempre funciono, ya no se espera menos de ti jaja gracias !

Comment: Excelente, que bien Felix, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builderr = new AlertDialog.Builder(principal.this);
builderr
  .setTitle("Guia para descargar los comprobantes de pago")
  .setMessage("1. Ingresa tu número de cédula \n2. Fecha de expedición de la cèdula\n3. Eps\n4. Selecciona el mes\n5. No soy un robot\n6. Generar Certificado" )
  .setCancelable(true)
  .setPositiveButton("Entiendo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse((""))));
    }
  }).create().show();
return true;
```

Comment: ¿Esta es una respuesta a la pregunta original o una continuación a tu otra publicación? Si es el segundo caso, ya se te mencionó que deberías formular una pregunta nueva. Además, debes emplear una sola publicación para tus preguntas y respuestas. Así que edítalas de ahora en adelante.