# Setear color y fuente a ciertas palabras de un item listview AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
private void obtenerLista() {
listaInformacion = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < listaPerso.size(); i++) {
    listaInformacion.add( " Id: " + listaPerso.get(i).getCodigo()  + " Nombre: " +listaPerso.get(i).getNombre() + " Contraseña: " + listaPerso.get(i).getContraseña());
}
```

}

Como ven en la imagen, estoy haciendo una base de datos sencilla, que en una listview muestre id nombre y contraseña. Quisiera que las palabras "id, nombre, contraseña" aparezcan en otro color y otro tipo de fuente, por ej negrita. Como deberia hacerlo ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el metodo `Html.fromHtml(...)` para dar formato al texto, este es un ejemplo usando los tags `<b>` y `</b>` para indicar un texto en bold:

```
private void obtenerLista() {
listaInformacion = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < listaPerso.size(); i++) {
    listaInformacion.add(Html.fromHtml(" <b>Id:</b> " + listaPerso.get(i).getCodigo()  + " <b>Nombre:</b> " +listaPerso.get(i).getNombre() + " <b>Contraseña:</b> " + listaPerso.get(i).getContraseña()));
}
```

Puedes revisar esta respuesta similar:

[Cambiar color y propiedades de texto en un AlertDialog](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44504/cambiar-color-y-propiedades-de-texto-en-un-alertdialog)

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta, habia leido de ese metodo pero no sabia bien como aplicarlo a mi codigo, una pregunta, al poner tal cual me has escrito, me pide que "listaInformacion = new ArrayList<String>();" pase a ser "listaInformacion = new ArrayList<Spanned>();" eso esta correcto? afectaría a la base de datos o no?