# Cambiar color del texto de los ítems de opciones de un dialogo

Tags: android, kotlin, alertdialog, text-color

Tengo este dialogo el cual las opciones salen con texto en color negro, y me gustaría ponerlo en blanco

```
@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
    private fun showPageSelectionDialog() {
        val options = arrayOf("A4", "A5") // Opciones para el usuario

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle)
        builder.setTitle("Selecciona el tamaño del PDF")
            .setItems(options) { _, which ->
                val selectedPageSize = if (which == 1) PageSize.A5 else PageSize.A4
                pdf(nombre.text.toString().trim(), selectedPageSize)
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar") { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }

        builder.create().show()
    }
```

Como uso más diálogos en mi app creé un estilo personalizado:

```
<!-- DIALOGO -->
    <style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Tambien use previamente:

```
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
```

Y no funcionó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como respondió [Jorgesys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95/jorgesys) en esta pregunta: [Cambiar color y propiedades de texto en un AlertDialog](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44504/cambiar-color-y-propiedades-de-texto-en-un-alertdialog/44505#44505), lo que me solucionó el problema ha sido añadir esta línea a mi variable options:

```
val options = arrayOf(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>A4</font>"),
                                Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>A5</font>"))
```

Aunque sea un método obsoleto, es el único que he encontrado que me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el color del texto en el diálogo a blanco, en lugar de definir `<item name="android:textAppearance">@color/white</item>`, define `<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>` :

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>   
</style>
```

Comment: Antes de usar `textAppereance` use `textColor` y nada, ambas no cambian el color de los textos de los items de las opciones